# Z-Function. String algorithms. Optimize for large strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, optimization

**The problem:**

> Given a string s. For each i from 1 to |s|, find the number of occurrences of its prefix of length i in the string.
>
> **Input:**
> The first line of input contains an integer q (1≤q≤10^5) — the number of datasets in the test.
>
> Each dataset consists of a string s. The length of the string s is from 1 to 10^6 characters. The string consists exclusively of lowercase Latin alphabet letters.
>
> The sum of the lengths of strings s across all q datasets in the test does not exceed 10^6.
>
> **Output:**
> For each dataset, output |s| integers c1, c2, ..., c|s|, where c[i] is the number of occurrences of the prefix of length i in the string s.
>
> **Example**
>
> *Input:*
>
> ```
> 5
> abacaba
> eeeee
> abcdef
> ababababa
> kekkekkek
> ```
>
> *Output:*
>
> ```
> 4 2 2 1 1 1 1 
> 5 4 3 2 1 
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 
> 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 
> 6 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1
> ```
>
> The task must be solved exclusively using the Z-function, and the total time for a string of length 10^6 characters should not exceed 2 seconds.

My solution looks like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    
    std::vector<int> ZFunc(const std::string& s) {
        const int sz = s.size();
        std::vector<int> z(sz, 0);
    
        for (int i = 1, l = 0, r = 0; i != sz; ++i) {
            if (r >= i)
                z[i] = std::min(z[i - l], r - i + 1);
    
            while (z[i] + i < sz && s[i + z[i]] == s[z[i]])
                z[i]++;
    
            if (z[i] > r - i + 1) {
                l = i;
                r = i + z[i] - 1;
            }
        }
    
        return z;
    }
    
    int main() {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
    
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> res(n);
    
        for (int k = 0; k != n; ++k) {
            std::string s;
            std::cin >> s;
    
            res[k].resize(s.size(), 1);
            std::vector<int> z = ZFunc(s);
    
            for (int i = 1; i != z.size(); ++i) {
                while (z[i]--)
                    res[k][z[i]]++;
            }
        }
    
        for (const auto& ivec : res) {
            for (int i : ivec)
                std::cout << i << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Its only issue is that I am exceeding the allowed time on tests, and I do not know how to optimize this algorithm. I suspect that the problem lies in strings of the form aaaaaa...aaabcd, where the number of identical characters is quite large, causing the algorithm to have a complexity of O(n^2).

**Algorithm Description:**

The essence of the proposed algorithm is as follows: we find the Z-function for each string. The i-th value of the Z-function represents the length of the matching prefix and substring at position i. More about the Z-function can be found [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html).

For each string, a prefix of length i occurs at least once, so initially, `res[k].resize(s.size(), 1);` is set to 1 for all prefixes of the string.

Since the task is to specify, for all i from 1 to |s|, the number of occurrences of a prefix of length i in the string s, when we look at a non-zero value of the Z-function at position i, it means that the prefix of length z[i] matches the substring of length z[i], starting at position i. This means we have found at least one more occurrence for all substrings of the prefix of length i.

For example:

```
s = abacaba
z = 0010301
```

When we reach i = 2, z[i] = 1, we can confidently increment the result res[0]++, as s[2]=s[0]='a'. We have found the first occurrence of the prefix of length 1. Next, z[4]=3, which means we have found a match for the prefix 'aba', including 'a', 'ab', and 'aba'. Therefore, for prefixes of length 3, 2, and 1, we add +1.

This is done in the following lines:

```cpp
while (z[i]--)
    res[k][z[i]]++;
```

Comment: *Its only issue is that I am exceeding the allowed time on tests* -- Are these tests taking into consideration this: `std::cout << std::endl` and other output functions?  If so, then it is not only the algorithm that is being timed -- it is other non-essential things such as I/O that are being thrown into the timing mix (when it shouldn't be).

Comment: you are doing a lot of extra work. [minimally tested](https://godbolt.org/z/769KqTqv5). Also note w.o your final sca loop, just `res[k] = ZFunc(s)`.

Comment: @JaMiT Edited my post, tried to explain what i did.

std::cout << std::endl quite fast, if you try to output vector of million int, it will be faster than 2 seconds

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In your example, shouldn't z be `7010301`?

Comment: @Beta The linked page says `z[0]` is of no importance and may just as well be taken to be `0`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: That is not what the text of the question says. Does the OP expect us to sift through linked documents to determine that this error was *inconsequential,* rather than something caused by a bug in the code or a misunderstanding of the algorithm?

Comment: @Beta I think i chose good algorithm but I'm missing something. perhaps there is better and faster way to solve this problem. I think I'm very close to the right solution

Comment: Beta is saying that if you use`0010301` as the example, you should state that `z[0]` is special in the question. In SO, external links are auxiliary and the question text itself need to be correct and self-contained without those links.

Comment: @vadyaov *std::cout << std::endl quite fast* -- Then to be honest with you, this task you have been given is suspect.  A true timing test would simply 1) Collect the test data, 2) start the timer, 2) Feed the algorithm with the test data and run the algorithm.  3) Stop the timer and determine the elapsed time  4) Output results.  Sticking output into the timing tests while the algorithm is running is bogus and is unacceptable.  No one would accept timing results with I/O thrown in, unless the timing tests are for I/O devices (hard drive speed, for example).

Comment: I think the `for(){while()...}}` loop in `main` is the problem. It looks as if you could reduce that from O(n^2) to O(n logn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's right way to solve this problem. Instead of my while loop, I could use cumulative sums for frequencies of prefix length i:
[answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288794/279295)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify and speed up your solution with the std::hashmap.

1. Use chars as keys and their occurence count as values.
2. Go through the string once and populate the hashmap.
3. Go through it again printing the occurence count of the respective character and decrease it's occurence count by 1.

This solution should have the time complexity of O(n)

Comment: Thank you, that's a good thought. However, my task is specifically to solve it using the Z-function.

Comment: OP mentioned - _find the number of occurrences of its prefix of length i in the string_. The solution you suggested is not accurate.

Comment: @H.S.
I know what you mean: something like this
std::count_if(z.begin() + 1, z.end() - i + 1, [i](int a) {return a >= i;});
But this solution is not better than my

Comment: @vadyaov My previous comment was for the solution suggested by Kamil Bizoń in his post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).